# invalid source html5 with windows phone 8.1 silverlight

Tags: html, cordova, video, visual-studio-cordova

I read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/09/26/html5-audio-and-video-improvements-for-windows-phone-8-1.aspx
that microsoft is supporting video html5 tag for wp8.1 but I am getting an **Invalid Source** message instead of my video stream.

I am 100% sure that the video is in the correct format because adding it to a native app using mediacontrol is working properly.

here is my html5 (I am using Cordova):

```
    <video src="www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" controls autoplay>
        HTML5 Video is required for this example
    </video>
```

I also tried with this

```
<video id="video1" width="420">
        <source src="www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

but in this case nothing is displayed on my phone.

How can I have a video on my screen and playing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the protocol (eg. "http://") to the resource name.

Try: src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"